# combine two formats together

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing the formatting of a dataframe. I need to do the thousand separator and the decimals. The problem is when I combine them together, only the last one is in effect. I guess many people may have the same confusion, as I have googled a lot, nothing is found.

I tried to use `.map(lambda x:('%.2f')%x and format(x,','))` to combine the two required formats together, but only the last one is in effect

```py
DF_T_1_EQUITY_CHANGE_Summary_ADE['Sum of EQUITY_CHANGE'].map(lambda x:format(x,',') and ('%.2f')%x)

DF_T_1_EQUITY_CHANGE_Summary_ADE['Sum of EQUITY_CHANGE'].map(lambda x:('%.2f')%x and format(x,','))
```

the first result is:

```
0    -2905.22
1    -6574.62
2     -360.86
3    -3431.95
Name: Sum of EQUITY_CHANGE, dtype: object
```

the second result is:

```
0    -2,905.2200000000003
1               -6,574.62
2                 -360.86
3    -3,431.9500000000003
Name: Sum of EQUITY_CHANGE, dtype: object
```

I tried a new way, by using

```
DF_T_1_EQUITY_CHANGE_Summary_ADE.to_string(formatters={'style1': '${:,.2f}'.format})
```

the result is:

```
Row Labels  Sum of EQUITY_CHANGE    Sum of TRUE_PROFIT  Sum of total_cost   Sum of FOREX VOL    Sum of BULLION VOL  Oil Sum of CFD VOL  Sum of BITCOIN VOL  Sum of DEPOSIT  Sum of WITHDRAW Sum of IN/OUT
0   ADE A BOOK USD  -2,905.2200000000003    638.09  134.83  15.590000000000002  2.76    0.0 0.0 0   0.0 0.0 0.0
1   ADE B BOOK USD  -6,574.62   -1,179.3299999999997    983.2099999999999   21.819999999999997  30.979999999999993  72.02   0.0 0   8,166.9 0.0 8,166.9
2   ADE A BOOK AUD  -360.86 235.39  64.44   5.369999999999999   0.0 0.0 0.0 0   700.0   0.0 700.0
3   ADE B BOOK AUD  -3,431.9500000000003    190.66  88.42999999999999   11.88   3.14    0.03    2.0 0   20,700.0    -30,000.0   -9,300.0
```

the result confuses me, as I set the .2f format which is not in effect.

Comment: I tried a new way:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the string formatter mini language you can add commas and set the decimals to 2 places using `f'{:,.2f}'`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'EQUITY_CHANGE': [-2905.219262257907,
  -6574.619531995241,
  -360.85959369471186,
  -3431.9499712161164]}
)

df.EQUITY_CHANGE.apply(lambda x: f'{x:,.2f}')
# returns:
0    -2,905.22
1    -6,574.62
2      -360.86
3    -3,431.95
Name: EQUITY_CHANGE, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

map method is not in-place; it doesn't modify the Series but instead it returns a new one.
So just substitute the result of the map to the old one

Here doc:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html